# Use of hyperledger fabric baseos and baseimage

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I just want to know the use of hyperledger fabric baseos and baseimage while spinning hyperledger fabric, as I don't see the containers running from baseos and baseimage.

Answer (score 3):

The **baseos** serves as a common base for building all images of fabric like peer, orderer, zookeeper, kafka, zookeeper, etc.

You will only need it if you build your fabric docker images from scratch.

The **baseimage** is used for building the chaincode container whenever you instantiate your chaincode on any channel.